# Rails user images broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, precompile

I've just deployed an app to Heroku and i did `rake assets:precompile`, but for some reason user generated images are not working. When a user uploads a profile picture for example, it saves BUT after a few minutes, when the page is refreshed. The image is broken and shows `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/user/image/2/avatar_cut.png")`

Any idea whats wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You should save the images to your public folder... `public/user/image/2/avatar_cut.png`

This way the images can be served without rails routing needing to be involved.

Comment: The "uploads" folder is in my public folder. I'm using `carrierwave::rmagick` as the uploader and the default is to store images in "uploads/model.class".